# How to configure jackson non null globally in Spring Boot 1.5.9

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jackson

I'm using a Spring Boot 1.5.9 and jackson 2.8.10. I would like to configure this `@JsonInclude(Include.NON_EMPTY)` annotation globally so that all the objects of my API are serialized following the rules of the annotation.

How I can get this?

I have tried to get through the `application.properties` file

```
spring.jackson.default-property-inclusion=non_null
```

and also through a configuration class:

```
@Primary
    @Bean
    public Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder objectMapperBuilder() {
        Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder builder = new Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder();
        builder.serializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);
        builder.serializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY);
        builder.failOnUnknownProperties(false);
        return builder;
    }
```

But none of this has an effect. It does not work

Does anyone know how to make this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `spring.jackson.default-property-inclusion=non_null` property is the best approach as it will be picked by `Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder` object. This should ensure that it will be applied everywhere.

This approach works in 2.0.0. I tested 1.5.9, 1.5.10, and 1.5.11 and 1.5.12 but neither of them worked with a simple test like:

```
@Autowired 
private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

@Test
public void shouldOutputEmpty() {
  Map<String, Object> obj = new HashMap<>();
  obj.put("a", null);
  String result = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(obj);
  assertThat(result).isEqualTo("{}");
}
```

This is strange because [Appendix A mentions this property](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.9.RELEASE/reference/html/common-application-properties.html). One way to resolve is to update Jackson to 2.9.X (Spring Boot 2.0.0 uses 2.9.4):

```
dependencyManagement {
  dependencies {
    dependency 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.9.4'
    dependency 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.9.4'
    dependency 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.9.4'
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you suggest then? Change my pom file to Spring Boot 2.0.0 version

Comment: @AlejoDev updating to Jackson 2.9 is one way to solve it. I won't dig deeper into it but it could be [Issue #1522](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/1522).

Comment: Where do I pay what you tell me, I can not find where. I'm using Maven

Comment: In Maven (`pom.xml`) or Gradle (`build.gradle`) project configuration you need to use 2.9 jackson dependencies. My example is for Gradle.